# Take information from saleforce and input into licence generating tool in browser and retrieve licence generated

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql

I am a computer science student intern and I have been given a project to complete in salesforce. I have never used salesforce before but have spent the last few weeks familiarising myself with it. The project requires me to create a button in account that takes asset information, and input that information into a licence generating tool in browser and return the licence number all from salesforce. I am unsure where to start and what steps I should take to complete this project. If anyone has any ideas that might help me would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This question may need some more details but I felt it is some thing interested and would like to learn more about it from some of the experts, so I am up voting this question

Comment: What do you mean by "into a licence generating tool in browser"?  Where does the "tool" execute?  External server?  Apex (within SF)?  Does the user need to input any data, or can SF gather everything it needs from existing data?

Comment: The licence generating tool is on a local company server. The user must input the data to generate the specific licence for the details entered for example a specific hardware item and software features.

Answer (score 1):

This is 100% something that needs to happen in VisualForce. I'm working through a similar issue myself - trying to get a contract to populate as HTML output, with some input fields (e.g. - payment information) and getting the information to map in and out from several different standard and custom objects.

I've been step-by-steping some test pages by following this guide: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_intro.htm

EDIT: 
Just found this guys question right above yours, which I feel is relevant: [Updating fields from multiple objects on a single visualforce page](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/56958/20264)

Comment: Thanks, I have access to a sandbox and have been looking at some visualForce pages that take input from user that are already in place. I think that if I get a field that takes user input using visualForce it would be a good start. Thanks for you help and good luck with your problem.