# Saving Opportunity and related Contact from single Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, controller, controller-extension

I have created a visualforce page that displays both opportunity and contact fields that I want users to be able to edit and save. I am using the opporutnity standard controller and added the following extension so as to be able to override (or add to) the standard save functionality with the 'SaveBoth' method (below). I am having trouble populating the contact object with the correct related record data.

I am recieveing the following error:

> "Invalid foreign key relationship: Opportunity.AccountId"

```
public with sharing class NewLeadControllerExtension 
{
    ApexPages.StandardController controller;
    public Opportunity oppt {get; set;}
    public Contact cont {get; set;}

    public NewLeadControllerExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
    {
        this.controller = controller;
        oppt = (Opportunity)controller.getRecord();
        cont = new Contact();
        cont.Id = oppt.Account.Contact.Id;
        //cont.AccountId = oppt.AccountId;
    }
    public PageReference SaveBoth()
    {
        controller.Save();
        update cont; 
        return null;
    }
}
```

I also tried using the line commented out in the code above instead of the line above it

```
cont.AccountId = oppt.AccountId
```

and received an

> "MISSING_ARGUMENT, Id not specified in an update call"

Any advice on how to populate the contact Id correctly?

Thanks!

I have researched everything I could find on this subject but still haven't managed to solve it. The code base I started from initially can be found at [Visualforce - Display fields from multiple objects](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/17364/visualforce-display-fields-from-multiple-objects/17365#17365)

Answer (score 2):

From the code you have posted, I see two issues with these lines of code:

```
cont = new Contact();
cont.Id = oppt.Account.Contact.Id;
```

Firstly, you aren't supposed to use an ID field that way. (EDIT:I should have said you SHOULDN'T use an ID field that way for an edit page. It is a perfectly valid way of doing it in some situations, as pointed out below). If it is an existing contact you should query it:

```
cont = [select id, whatever from Contact where Id = :x];
```

Which brings me to the second issue. You can't go from Account down to a contact, unless you have an additional lookup relationship to Contact (though I wouldn't really recommend that). I'm not even sure what you are trying to do with that line.

Comment: Thank you for your response! What I am attempting to do is to instantiate a contact object, populate it with the correct values that are related to the opportunity (through Id relationship) , and then update it with any changes from the user Visualforce page. Basically I want the save operation to save both the standard primary object (Opportunity) AND the related object (Contact) at the same time.  Hope that makes sense. Regards

Comment: Hey raffters, setting an id like this is actually a legit way to do updates. Very useful in situations where you're close to the SOQL query limit for instance and is more performant overall.

Comment: Thanks @LaceySnr I didn't mean to mislead anyone. I personally find that way to be of rather limited use, but opinions will vary.

Comment: @DavidLeckenby - The question I intended raise (though didn't do well reading it while more awake), was: How are the Opportunity and Contact related?

Comment: Thanks @raffters Opportunity is related to Contact through the Account object. From the Opportunity there is a many to one relationship with Account and from Account to Contact there is a one to many relationship. Also Contact records can be queried as they have the exact same name as the Account record. Regards

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a lookup to contact from the Account or are you using person accounts?

If the former, then your field would be called something like `Contact__c` at a guess and you'd want to do:

```
cont.Id = oppt.Account.Contact__c;
```

If the latter, then the field will be `oppt.Account.ContactId` if I remember correctly.

If you're not using either of those approaches then you need to query for a contact to use, as contacts are child records of accounts, not the other way around, meaning an account could have many contacts and not just one.

Comment: Many Thanks Matt! Our org is not configured for Personal Accounts (even though they use Business and Personal Account record types). Anyhow I think what you suggested is right about querying the contact. So I declared and instantiated an Account object and then added the following `code acct.id = oppt.AccountId;
cont.Id = [SELECT Contact.id FROM Contact WHERE Contact.Name = Account.Name];`   I am now getting an invalid binding expression error....Thanks so much for your help :)

Comment: Hi Matt. I have worked more on this issue but still have not succeeded in being able to update the contact object (the opportunity saves no problem). I have with your assistance added a query statement that enables me to acquire the correct contact id, but I still cannot mange to update any contact fields on the visualforce page?

Comment: Is the page writing to that contact object which is initiated in the controller? Looks like it should be working, just make sure you're not creating a new contact in memory on save.

Comment: There is only one visualforce page which has a standard opportunity controller and the controller extension shown above. Could I post you the page to look at? If so, where would be the best place to do that, in this comment field?

Comment: The best bet is to edit the question, but I suspect you don't have the rep for that. If you can't, post it as a comment and I'll do it for you.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me Matt. I have now solved it. I changed the assignment query to  'cont = [SELECT Id, Rating__c, Name, Lead_Source__c, MobilePhone FROM Contact WHERE Name =: acct.Name LIMIT 1];' and my visualforce call to '<apex:inputField value="{!cont.Rating__c}"/>' and it all worked. Thanks again